# procexp.exe has high CPU usage

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance, cpu

Once in a while The system starts consuming a 5-6 times more CPU than usual.
For instance if usually procexp.exe CPU usage is ~3%, it can get to 15-20% in that period.

In my opinion, this is not a problem with some specific process but rather hardware/OS.

The CPU temperature is below 50 deg. The RAM is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with the laptop's battery, regardless if it was plugged in to the electricity source.

I have re-imaged the laptop and it didn't fix the problem.
Then I've changed the battery and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Use resource monitor to see what is spiking the cpu cycles

In the start search box type "resmon" without quotes to open it, then click the cpu tab, then click the cpu column header to sort it by highest or lowest number of cpu cycles,

[image]

.

Occasional spikes are nothing to worry about but if cpu cycles get used constantly at high numbers see the links below.

If it is an application causing high usage, [see this article](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140264-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-caused-by-apps/)

If it is DPC Interrupt causing it [see this article](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/)

Answer (score 0):

Check your hard drive temp and also run some diagnostic's.

I changed from a 7200 RPM SATA drive to a 'hybrid' SSD/SATA and my usual/idle CPU load has dropped several %.

Check what times etc you've got your anti-virus scan/update, windows update and windows backup set to run...

Comment: In the process explorer I don't see any unusual processes running.  It's just every process takes more x times more CPU than usual.

Comment: Checked your kernel load within the performance task manager, is it higher during these times or still normal?